# Property/field arithmetics on object/struct array in Matlab

Tags: matlab, object, struct

Given two struct arrays A and B with field f1:

```
A = struct('f1',{1,2,3})
B = struct('f1', {4,5,6})
```

you can assign the contents of the f1 fields of struct array A to the fields of B by

```
[B.f1] = A.f1
```

but I cannot figure out what to do if you want to perform arithmetics on the field, for instance if you want to store the negative of the f1 fields of A in B.

```
[B.f1] = -A.f1
```

does not work, you need to first concatenate the elements of A in order for the operator to work

```
-[A.f1]
```

but then the result is a vector, which somehow you need to "unwrap" in order to match the number of output arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `num2cell`:

```
tmp=num2cell(-[A.f1]);
[B.f1]=tmp{:};
```

Result:

```
B.f1

ans =
    -1
ans =
    -2
ans =
    -3
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried using `deal` but without `num2cell` and it appears that it's actually `num2cell` that does all the heavy lifting. It's not even necessary to use `deal`, `[B.f1]=tmp{:};` works just as well.